# My weird laptop does not block forbidden site without using any VPN addon or software, but how?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vpn, proxy, blocking

Here is the story, I have **two laptop**, one is the **older** (much older) and the other one is **new**. The **old one** has windows 10 installed and a bunch of app and many add-on and extension for Chrome and Firefox.

I frequently open many blocked website from my country (or ISP blocked sites) and it was **flawless experience**, like you just need to type in the website and will go to the website and **the speed is fast too** (not like when you open blocked site via VPN or proxy).

I thought I can do the same in **my new laptop (Windows 8)**, but **I can't do that** in my old laptop, the new laptop need chrome extension/firefox addon or VPN software or even proxies, most of those method are paid service, the free one is slow.

So, I want to **replicate** my browsing experience from my old laptop to my new laptop, **I went on to investigate** is there any specific addon/extension or even a software that I install on my old laptop that could do the same in my new laptop, and **no luck so far**, turns out **no VPN software installed** in my old laptop, and after **I tried to disable all addon/extension that related to VPN in chrome and firefox (in my old laptop)**, **I still could go** to blocked website **flawlessly**. It seems to me that my old laptop has a magic inside it.

Can you help me to find the possible causes for this behavior in my old laptop (so I could replicate it on my new one)?

Comment: synchronize google chrome settings+extensions to the new one.

Comment: for note: my flawless experience also happen in firefox on my old laptop, tried before but no-luck so far, my new laptop still block forbidden site or redirect it to other site (those two laptops are connected on same house wifi)

Comment: Any answers here will be speculation unless you actually record what is happening on the wire.  So load wireshark or MS netmon on each laptop and simply record what happens on each laptop's network when you attempt the same page.  Flush your DNS first to ensure a proper comparison and to make sure that you record everything needed.

Comment: Are you asking us, if you have an add-on installed on your old system, that could explain this behavior?  Transfer your Chrome/Firefox profile to your new computer see if that helps.  There are lots of proxy add-ons that exist that would explain your ability to view blocked websites on your old computer.  You should edit your question with this information.  To put it simply, you have not provided enough information, for us to give you any meanful explaination of the behavior you have witnessed.

Answer (score -1):

One possible explanation is that the old laptop had different DNS settings than your ISP's default.
Go to Network Connections -> open the Properties window for your connection -> select Internet Protocol v4 and click Configure. Look for alternative DNS servers, and copy them to your new computer.

Comment: already check that, yes the second laptop got some manual DNS number while the old one use automatic DNS, but still the forbidden site will get directed/blocked if we access from new laptop.